# Silverlight/WPF/WP 7 Integration

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-5.0

Has anyone heard as these tools get better and better if they are planning on either creating a more reusable code-base between all of these products or at least more of a common code-base?  It seems how close these products are, that some sort of shared component feature should be available?

Maybe that's a feature in the upcoming Silverlight 5.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Portable Libary Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/01/19/announcing-portable-library-tools-ctp-justin-van-patten.aspx) project was announced at PDC last year. You can view the details of the session by Shawn Burke in the [3-Screen Coding: Sharing code between Windows Phone, Silverlight, and .NET](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Schedule/Sessions) session. The CTP of the tool s(see first link) was released in January.